# How to give a softbody a collision shape in Godot 4

Tags: 3d, godot, softbody

I'm trying to give my softbody a collision shape so that it interacts with staticbodys. Basically i'm trying to drape a cloth over a randomized pattern of staticbodys (which are cubes), and currently the softbody is phasing through them.

Thank you!